# Cannot mount lvm, bad superblock

Tags: mount, lvm

I've got a 2TB HDD with an LVM /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv that will not mount.

```
mike@bambam:~> sudo mount  /dev/ubuntu-vg/root ./mnt/mnt1
mount: /home/mike/mnt/mnt1: can't read superblock on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root.
```

Looking  in to it a bit more

```
mike@bambam:~> sudo mke2fs -n /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
mke2fs 1.46.4 (18-Aug-2021)
Creating filesystem with 240228352 4k blocks and 60063744 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 7b1f64a6-4204-4de7-806b-3d21468a8e41
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
        32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
        4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
        102400000, 214990848

mike@bambam:~> sudo dumpe2fs /dev/ubuntu-vg/root  | grep -i superblock
dumpe2fs 1.46.4 (18-Aug-2021)
dumpe2fs: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/ubuntu-vg/root
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

I did look at using mke2fs on the partition itself but bailed

```
mike@bambam:~> sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdg3
mke2fs 1.46.4 (18-Aug-2021)
/dev/sdg3 contains a LVM2_member file system
Proceed anyway? (y,N) n
```

Other information that has been requested in other posts

```
mike@bambam:~> sudo pvscan
  PV /dev/sdg3   VG ubuntu-vg       lvm2 [1.82 TiB / 1.62 TiB free]
  Total: 1 [1.82 TiB] / in use: 1 [1.82 TiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

mike@bambam:~> sudo lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv' [200.00 GiB] inherit

mike@bambam:~> sudo lvs
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-a----- 200.00g   

mike@bambam:~> sudo fsck -y /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
fsck from util-linux 2.37.2
e2fsck 1.46.4 (18-Aug-2021)
fsck.ext2: Input/output error while trying to open /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

mike@bambam:~> sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdg
[sudo] password for root: 
Disk /dev/sdg: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: USB 3.0         
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EECFD2EC-89E8-4417-AE09-0AEA8F1A13E9

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdg1     2048       4095       2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/sdg2     4096    2101247    2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdg3  2101248 3907026943 3904925696  1.8T Linux filesystem
```

Comment: You missed the obvious thing: Are there any kernel messages (`journalctl -f` or so)?

Comment: Thanks for responding. It turns out there was a bit of an operator error in that I was trying to examine 2 HDDs, they had similar but different LVM names, albeit both created  from dd (go figure !). To get to an LVM I had to figure out which LVM was active, deactivate it, then activate the one on the HDD that was plugged in. Only then could I fsck and mount the LVM.

Comment: So please either write an answer to your own question (if you think it's valuable for others, too), or just delete the question if you feel you have asked something stupid. If you decide to keep the question, please add some more details to the question (or in the answer), too.